# JACo mp3 Player

Tags: java, mp3

```
import jaco.mp3.player.MP3Player;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        File f = new File ("001.mp3");  
        MP3Player mp3 = new MP3Player(f);
        mp3.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e);}
}
}
```

It plays the first second only then stops, I tried many different mp3 files but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that the mp3 player is shutted down because the java program terminates his execution. You could try hanging the java thread with a sleep.
This should works:

```
try{
  File f = new File ("001.mp3");  
  MP3Player mp3 = new MP3Player(f);
  mp3.play();
  while(!mp3.isStopped()){
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
}
catch(Exception e){
System.err.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://sites.google.com/site/teachmemrxymon/java/how-to-use-mp3player-class

I had this same problem and found this, attaching the play action to a button and working from there will play the track in full.

Comment: The main idea is to invoke method `.play()` from different thread rather than from main.